# How to limit to store the no of views in session for prime faces application

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

We are using primefaces 2.2.1 version in our application. We would like to restrict to store the no of views storing in session to 3. I have configured my web.xml like as :

```
<context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default).See JSF  Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <description>The maximum number of logical views (GET requests) to store per session (http://tinyurl.com/yw6f2e)</description>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews</param-name>
    <param-value>3</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <description>The maximum number of JSF views (POST requests) stored in the session for per logical view (http://tinyurl.com/yw6f2e)</description>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession</param-name>
    <param-value>3</param-value>
</context-param>
```

It seems that , this configuration is not working. I have found 15 views storing  in session, when i look at the memory heap dumps.

Using Primefaces 2.2.1, JSF 2.0.9 running on Mojarra 2.0.9

Any ideas...

Comment: I am using:

JSF 2.0.9 Primefaces 2.2.1

Comment: Are you using Mojarra or MyFaces?

Comment: If you look at the source code [link](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/faces/config/WebConfiguration.java.html) the param-name looks fine but looks like it is deprecated.

Comment: Is there any way to find no of views stored in session programatically ,instead of relying on heap dumps

Comment: I haven't tried this but it might work [link](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2006/06/27/jsf_state_saving_best_of/) for getting the list of views.

Comment: I am observing nearly the same behavior both on GlassFish 4.1 (JEE7) and Tomcat 8 (Spring), both running on Mojarra. These two context-param show no effect. Exactly 25 Views will be opened (@PostConstruct calls) before the number gets stable (though @PreDestroy calls), on both platforms. Is this just the wrong context-param name, or is this a bug?

Comment: I am using: JSF 2.0.9 (mojaraa 2.0.9) , same problem please help